# Returning Field names as part of a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a Sql Satement that gets passed any valid SQL subquery, and return the the resultset, WITH HEADERS.

Somehow i need to interrogate the resultset, get the fieldnames and return them as part of a "Union" with the origional data, then pass the result onwards for exporting.

Below my attempt: I have a Sub-Query Callled "A", wich returns a dataset and i need to query it for its fieldnames. ?ordinally maybe?

```
select A.fields[0].name, A.fields[1].name, A.fields[2].name  from 
(

Select 'xxx1' as [Complaint Mechanism]  , 'xxx2' as [Actual Achievements]
union ALL 
Select 'xxx3' as [Complaint Mechanism]  , 'xxx4' as [Actual Achievements]
union ALL 
Select 'xxx5' as [Complaint Mechanism]  , 'xxx6' as [Actual Achievements]   ) as A
```

Any pointers would be appreciated (maybe i am just missing the obvious...)

The Resultset should look like the table below:

```
F1                      F2
---------------------   ---------------------
[Complaint Mechanism]   [Actual Achievements]
xxx1                    xxx2
xxx3                    xxx4
xxx5                    xxx6
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want the output to look?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: SQL 2012 / 2014

Comment: I've never seen the index[0] in the select statement. Are you getting an error when you run the above query? I would think it would throw a syntax error.

Comment: I am getting an error. Thats the part i need help on - getting the right syntax for retrieving the fieldname of the subquery.

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be in one query? Is that a strict requirement? Eg from your presentation layer (C#, Java, ...) you could analyze the resultset and have the first row contain the column names you found in that analysis.

Comment: And will you always be returning 2 columns?

Comment: I could analyze the result-set in C# (more overhead and design issues here), but if i can get the info in one result-set, straight from the db source, with no db-cursors, it would be great....

Comment: From experience, I know what you are proposing is not the way to go. The results of your query have specific types (eg, INT, DATETIME, NVARCHAR(16), FLOAT, DECIMAL...). If you would make a query to add the column names to the results, you would have to CAST/CONVERT each  column of the original query to some sort of (N)VARCHAR(XXX). Also, each environment I know of (like C#) allows for very easy inspection of the resultset to get the column names associated with each result column. You will have an easier time taking my advise then creating a query that adds the column names as the first row.

Comment: Most helpful comment in helping me structure a solution for my situation. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a static number of columns, you can put your data into a temp table and then query `tempdb.sys.columns` to get the column names, which you can then `union` on top of your data.  If you will have a dynamic number of columns, you will need to use dynamic SQL to build your `pivot` statement but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

The one caveat here is that all data under your column names will need to be converted to strings:

```
select 1 a, 2 b
into #a;

select [1] as FirstColumn
        ,[2] as SecondColumn
from (
    select column_id
            ,name
    from tempdb.sys.columns
    where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#a')
    ) d
pivot (max(name)
        for column_id in([1],[2])
        ) pvt

union all

select cast(a as nvarchar(100))
    ,cast(b as nvarchar(100))
from #a;
```

Query Results:

```
| FirstColumn | SecondColumn |
|-------------|--------------|
|      a      |      b       |
|      1      |      2       |
```